# Failed to load QCARWrapper.dll

Tags: unity, c#, vuforia

I am using unity 5.1.0f(64 bit) and  Vuforia SDK Version: vuforia-unity-5-0-5

The web cam is operating normally in windows but in unity in Play Mode not.

I am getting an error message
"failed to load QCARWrapper.dll: expected 64bit architecture..."

Can anybody help out solving this issue?

Comment: Can you try moving the QcarWrapper files from /Plugins to /Plugins/x86?

Comment: @SanSolo : Plugins/x86 is this a folder in the project?

Comment: Yes, in unity. You need to create sub folder Assets/Plugins/x86.

Comment: @SanSolo : Its still not working. The camera out is not displaying.Its showing the same error.

Comment: This question has been answered multiple times, simply google a bit and you would have gotten the exact same answers.

Answer (score 2):

**Vuforia 5.0** supports the **32bit** version of the Unity Editor on **Windows**, and the **64bit** version **on Mac**.

So, **There are two possible solutions:**

1. you just need to install and use the Unity 5 32bit Editor, on Windows.

***OR***

2. Create a new folder **"x86"** inside

   **Assets>>Plugins**

   inside your unity project structure
   Then move the following files from **"Plugins"** to newely created **"x86"** folder.

   - QCARWrapper.lib
   - QCARWrapper.dll
   - QCARWrapper.dll.signature
   - QCARWrapper.exp

After that check log message, If you see the log like:

```
Setting platform to 'Editor' for plugin: Assets/Plugins/x86/VuforiaWrapper.dll
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.ExtensionImport:UpdatePluginSettings() (at Assets/Vuforia/Editor/Scripts/ExtensionImport.cs:43)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

Then , **Congrats !! You are ready to Go!**

**FYI More Info:**

You need to use the Installer to download and install the additional Android support component, by selecting it from the list of the available components in the Installer wizard;